Use IOUtils.setByteArrayMaxOverride in pyspark
I'm facing the error
"org.apache.poi.util.RecordFormatException: Tried to allocate an array of length 100,335,238, but the maximum length for this record type is 100,000,000."
when trying to read an excel file using pyspark in databricks. That's my syntax:
spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
          .option("header", "true") \
          .schema(input_schema) \
          .load(path) \
          .display()

I just updated my excel maven package on my computer cluster to "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.5.1_0.20.4" but that does not help either. My cluster is running on databricks runtime version 15.4 LTS.
So, the error message indicates that my excel file (14 MB) is just a little too big to be read. My AI assistant (as well as my google research) tell me that one solution to the problem is to increase the "maximum record length" above 100,000,000. This can be done using the command IOUtils.setByteArrayMaxOverride(200000000). But this syntax is Java syntax. So, the question is how to increase this size using pyspark/Python? Or maybe there is another (better) approach to deal with the problem?

I just found the answer myself:
spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
          .option("header", "true") \
          .option("maxByteArraySize", 200000000) \    # that's the solution!
          .schema(input_schema) \
          .load(path) \
          .display()

Source
